# How to split string and extract required string?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following string:

> +CMGR: "REC READ","919742400000",,"2014/02/21 23:35:52+22"
> Hi SMSApp
> OK

I need to extract the data between each pair of double quotes.  Here is the resulting data that I need to extract:

- REC READ
- 919742400000
- 2014/02/21 23:35:52+22
- Hi SMSApp

How do I split the string and extract the required data?

Comment: `","`  and `",,"` are also inside double quotes. And also show us what  you have done.

Comment: Please be more specific.  What part of the task are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?  What didn't work about it?

Comment: I only need to extract the datas I mentioned before. comma and double commas are not required. I have written code for receiving SMS and display it. It is working. The only problem I have is getting the formatted text as mentioned above because I have no knowledge about Regular Expressions. I need to extract SMS status, Originating mobile number, Date Time Stamp and message and put each data in a row of DataGridView.

Comment: Hi, No, I have not yet tried your code. I will try it soon and reply.

Comment: Hi Steven, I tried your code in my VC#.Net application but it gives exception error in run time. The code compiles without errors or warnings. Please provide a sample VC# and BV.Net code to extract the above data from a string variable and display them in a RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches( inputString, @"""(.+)"",""(.+)"",,""(.+)""\s*(.+)\s*OK", RegexOptions.None | RegexOptions.Multiline );

string a = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
string b = matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
string c = matches[0].Groups[3].Value;
string d = matches[0].Groups[4].Value;
```